# JPA Criteria Specification for ManyToMany

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I had entities `Client` and `Agency` with ManyToOne relation, so that table `client` had column `agency_id` pointing to table `agency`, also `Client` had:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "agency_id")
private Agency agency;
```

There were Spring Data JPA specification to select `Client`'s with `Agency` id's in:

```
public static Specification<Client> withAgencyIds(Collection<Long> agencyIds) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> root.join(Client_.agency).get(Agency_.id).in(agencyIds);
}
```

Now I have to change ManyToOne relation to ManyToMany relation, so that `Client` have:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "client_agency",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "agency_id"))
@OrderBy("name")
private List<Agency> agencies = new ArrayList<>();
```

How should I tune the specification above in order to select `Client`'s having `Agency` id's?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Doesn't `root.join(Client_.agencies)` work for you? Not sure what you expect the logic of the modified query to be

Comment: Thank you for response, actually it was the first thing I thought about but I'm not sure if such a specification select exactly clients that agency_id's are in given id's, will try to test it.

Comment: @crizzis It works fine, you can answer separately so that I could voted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This JPA Criteria specification works fine:

```
public static Specification<Client> withAgencyIds(Collection<Long> agencyIds) {
    return (root, query, cb) -> root.join(Client_.agencies).get(Agency_.id).in(agencyIds);
}
```